# Shape of molecular bonds

Tags: molecules

I'd like to model some simple molecules using VSEPR. With what functions should I approximate the sigma and pi bond orbitals?
A simple Gauss would do it?
I'd like to have a good precision.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This may be a question better suited to [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This is a physics question, Charlie.

Comment: It is *at very least* in the region between physics and chemistry. Anything relating to modelling of molecular bonds is arguably computational/quantum chemistry territory. If you don't get an answer here you should try asking on Chemistry SE also.

Comment: It is a question in between, where either will be eligible to downvote in want of any information arguing it belongs to the other side.

Comment: I might be biased because my background is in chemistry, but this topic strikes me as leaning further toward the chemistry side of things.

Comment: Or create a SE question for this instead of deflecting my topic.